# GET request - unable to do a SELECT statement from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I will be sending a request to the PHP code through a `GET` request. it will have several parameters passed. I will be using these parameters in the WHERE clause of my select statement.

**GET REQUEST**

http:// localhost/server/person.php?Id=1&age=12&hieght=100

**PHP code**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pwd");
if (!$connection )
  {
  die('FAIL: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("db", $connection );
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person where hieght='$_GET[hieght]");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
```

i think my PHP code is wrong. I am not sure if this is the way to grab variables from a `GET` request.

Comment: `'$_GET[hieght]` seems you're missing the closing `'`, should be `'$_GET[hieght]'`, and btw, this is `very` prone to SQL injection, take some time to clean it up or use `PDO` instead.

Comment: you beat me to it. But also, use 'height' instead of 'hieght', that might be another typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a variable from `$_GET` use, as an example to get height from `$_GET` array you can write

```
$height=$_GET['height'];
```

so you can write

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person where hieght='".$hieght."'");
```

or you can write

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person where hieght='".$_GET['height']."'");
```

**Update:**

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent sql injection, like

```
$height=$_GET['height'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person where hieght='".mysql_real_escape_string($hieght)."'");
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person where hieght='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['height'])."'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$height = $_GET['hieght']; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person where hieght='$height'");
```

Instead of

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person where hieght='$_GET[hieght]");
```

> Note that with this code it is very likely to be victim of sql
>   injection

Comment: How do i fix it, could you help me

Comment: @Illep, you have a lot of answers and comments received, read it and do it.

Comment: Not the answers, i am asking about the SQL injection comment you made

Comment: @Illep, it has been asked and discussed in many places, help yourself by researching. should help you understand it.

Answer (score 1):

you may also wanna use this concat:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person where hieght='".$_GET['hieght']."'");
```

Comment: It should be `$_GET['hieght']` not `$_GET[hieght]`

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person where hieght='".$_GET['hieght']."'");
```

A good debug technique when you are feeling your your is to put the SQL into a string
that you can log and see if it is what you expected.
Using mysql_error() after the query may have given you a hint too...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Person where hieght='".$_GET['hieght']."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
#Not for production code, but handy while learning - error goes into web server log.
error_log("SQL=$sql, error=".mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be parsing input like that for injections:

```
<?php

    $myHeight = mysql_reaL_escape_string($_GET['height']);

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pwd");
    if (!$connection )
    {
        die('FAIL: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("db", $connection );
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person where height=$myHeight");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
```

Secondly, you should also be using the [PHP PDO](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) object rather than the old mysql_query etc.